# Python - Error when performing an update statement in Salesforce

Tags: python-3.x, salesforce, insert-update

I am trying to perform an update query on an object in Salesforce using the below query:

```
fieldInfo = {
'account_id' : '0000123',    
'Name' : 'Prod A',
'LastSaleDate' : '2018-01-04'}

sf_data_cursor.Account.update(fieldInfo)
```

I however encounter the below error

```
TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
```

I am trying to perform this update query via Python script. Please note, create query works just fine. Could anyone assist on this. Thanks.

**Update:**

Query to create record:

```
fieldInfo = {
'account_id' : 'xyz123',    
'Name' : 'Prod-C',
'LastSaleDate' : '2017-12-09'}
sf_data_cursor.Account.create(fieldInfo)

Output: OrderedDict([('id', '0015B00000SBMdXQAX'), ('success', True), ('errors', [])])
```

Comment: looks like you are missing a filed when updating. Can you paste your create as well?

Comment: @yash, I have updated the original message with the query to create a record.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this but using the below code:

```
sf_data_cursor.Account.update('0015B445523e', {'account_id' : '0000123'})
```

Comment: did you know why it's fixed because of the above code?

Comment: In the update syntax we just need to refer to the unique Id value and then mention which rows need to be updated. Whereas when we create we just enter values for all columns and Salesforce generates the unique id for that row. Hope this helps.

Comment: You need to use the Record Management syntax, not Bulk Update; see https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce#record-management